# "No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first." in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been encountering an error in my VB.Net code that says "No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.". I was trying to code a live search on 3 datagrids and only 2 of them are working even though they have the same code. Please help me.

Here is the code for the datagrid live search that encounters an error:

```
Private Sub txtProdSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProdSearch.TextChanged

    Connect()
    Query = "select * from tbl_productdetails where name like '%' @name '%' or code like '%' @code '%'"

    With Command
        .CommandText = Query
        .Connection = Conn
        .Parameters.Clear()
        .Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProdSearch.Text.Trim
        .Parameters.Add("@code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProdSearch.Text.Trim

        Reader = .ExecuteReader
    End With

    dgProd.Rows.Clear()

    While Reader.Read
        dgProd.Rows.Add(Reader("code"), Reader("name"), Reader(2), Reader(3), Reader(4))
    End While
End Sub
```

And here is a code of one of the working datagrid live search:

```
Private Sub txtSearchTrans_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchTrans.TextChanged
    Connect()
    Query = "select * from tbl_sales where transaction_num like '%' @transaction_num '%'"

    With Command
        .CommandText = Query
        .Connection = Conn
        .Parameters.Clear()
        .Parameters.Add("@transaction_num", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearchTrans.Text.Trim

        Reader = .ExecuteReader
    End With

    dgSales.Rows.Clear()

    While Reader.Read
        dgSales.Rows.Add(Reader("transaction_num"), Reader(1), Reader(2))
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really6 know how much clearer the error message could be. You seem to be just ignoring what it's telling you. That said, you're going about this all wrong anyway. Don't add rows to the grid one by one. Create a `DataTable` and call its `Load` method to populate it from the data reader, then bind that to the grid, preferably via a `BindingSource`. Not only will that create the rows, it will also create the columns if they don't already exist.

Comment: I feel bad for your end user who types one character in txtSearchTrans then the UI halts while it hits the database. You should kick off a timer with each keystroke (call Change on a timer cancel previous keystroke for example) then in a background thread, or with Async, hit the database and invoke the UI calls back to the UI thread. This won't solve your problem (probably the previous comment will) but it is certainly something you should consider.

Comment: What djv has said is true but I would take it one step further.  Load the entire data table into memory, then do your search on that using either Filter or Linq expressions,  Means one hit to the DB rather than once per keystroke

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've been approaching GridViews.  First the HTML:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="gv" ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="FixedHeader" DataKeyNames="ThingID" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="View Thing Details" 
        HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" ControlStyle-Width="120px">
    </asp:ButtonField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thing ID"
        HeaderStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-Width="75px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblThingID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ThingID")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can add as many template fields as you want and style however you like.  Then on the vb side:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Sub gvLoad()

    Dim con as new SqlConnection(YourConString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim RecordCount As Integer = 0

    Dim Query as string ="SELECT ThingID FROM tbl_things"
    con.open()
    cmd = new SqlCommand(Query,con)
    dt = new DataTable
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    RecordCount = da.fill(dt)
    con.close()
    
    gv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    gv.DataBind()

End Sub
```

You can do a lot more to 'pretty it up' and a Try/Catch is always a good idea but this is the basic idea: Create column templates for your gv with HTML and then load the whole thing up with a DataTable.

Hopefully that helps.